# Extra Spacing Between Rows in Outlook 2010

Tags: html, css, outlook, html-email, outlook-2010

I'm using a table to fake a bulleted list in my HTML email. It looks great in every client except Outlook 2010, which adds extra white space between each row:

[image: correct vs outlook]

The table `cellpadding` and `cellspacing` is set to 0 and I tried explicitly setting the `line-height` in each table row.

The code:

```
<table width="100%" style="table-layout: fixed; margin-bottom: 21px; border: none;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="15" valign="top" style="border-collapse: collapse;">&bull;</td>
    <td width="485" valign="top" style="border-collapse: collapse;">Satisfy the PSD2 requirement for Strong Customer Authentication (SCA)</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="15" valign="top" style="border-collapse: collapse;">&bull;</td>
    <td width="485" valign="top" style="border-collapse: collapse;">Help you comply with GDPR and minimize the risk of potential penalties</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="15" valign="top" style="border-collapse: collapse;">&bull;</td>
    <td width="485" valign="top" style="border-collapse: collapse;">Reduce friction to improve your user experience</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the `margin-bottom` style applied to the parent `table`. Outlook applies that style to the child elements so each td has a bottom margin of `21px`. Remove the bottom margin and use a blank table row to fake a bottom margin instead:

```
<table width="100%" class="list-table" style="table-layout: fixed; border: none;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="15" valign="top" style="border-collapse: collapse;">&bull;</td>
    <td width="485" valign="top" style="border-collapse: collapse;">Satisfy the PSD2 requirement for Strong Customer Authentication (SCA)</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="15" valign="top" style="border-collapse: collapse;">&bull;</td>
    <td width="485" valign="top" style="border-collapse: collapse;">Help you comply with GDPR and minimize the risk of potential penalties</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="15" valign="top" style="border-collapse: collapse;">&bull;</td>
    <td width="485" valign="top" style="border-collapse: collapse;">Reduce friction to improve your user experience</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="100%" height="21" colspan="2" style="border-collapse: collapse;">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Hmmm havent heard of outlook doing that but its good to know. Would like to replicate this in Outlooks.All Outlooks are doing that or 2007+ ?

Comment: This is exactly what happened to me - thank you for pointing this out. Removing padding on parent table also removed weird spacing between that table's rows.

Answer (score 0):

“Remove the bottom margin” does not work for me. I ended up adding a blank row as the last row like this:

```
<tr>
   <td style="height:0;font-size:0;line-height:0;">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
```